# Why am I removed?

Tags: support, user-accounts, reputation

I just noticed that I received a "User removed" message from The Workplace last week, and my rep is reduced by 15. The funny part of this is that I haven't visited this section for few weeks.

So may I know what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: see detailed explanation at MSO: [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/165773)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't from *you* being removed. Some other user was removed. When a user is removed, all of the votes cast by that user go away. In this case, it seems a user was removed who cast upvotes on your posts (three upvotes on questions is +15, or one answer and one question). Since these votes have gone away, the reputation you gained from them has been lost as well.

Comment: I have seen many people on many different SE-network sites asking the same thing the past couple days. My guess is that a script was run that cleaned up some users recently, and that is the cause of the hubbub in this case.